# JSHint some errors

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Why JSHint say me:

> JSHint: Missing semicolon (W033)
>   For the `'use strict'`
>   and
>
> JSHint: 'myApp' is not defined. (W117)

***controller.js:***

```
'use strict'
myApp.controller('NavbarCtrl', function NavbarController($scope, $location) {
    $scope.routeIs = function (routeName) {
        return $location.path() === routeName;
    };
});
...
```

Comment: first, add semicolon after first line, like: `'use strict';`

Comment: while using strict mode, need to add each and every piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've already opened a similar question and now this. Please ask all similar question in single post.

Here's the updated code that'll work for you.

```
/* global myApp*/ //if myApp is defined in some file globally.
'use strict';

var myApp; // if myApp is not defined earlier.
myApp.controller('NavbarCtrl', function NavbarController($scope, $location) {
    $scope.routeIs = function (routeName) {
        return $location.path() === routeName;
    };
});
...
```

Answer (score 1):

Both the errors are self explanatory.

> JSHint: Missing semicolon (W033) For the 'use strict' and

Add the semicolon after `use strict;`

> JSHint: 'myApp' is not defined. (W117)

It means the `myApp` is not defined. You can simply define it like this:

```
var myApp
```